# VS Code Timeline view isn't collapsed by default (circa v1.84)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm opening Visual Studio Code the timeline view is being expanded by default all the time. I've to manually collapse it or make it invisible by right clicking and then unchecking the timeline option in the side bar.

This issue is happening recently, it behaved normal before.

[Expanded Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wLNl.png)

[Collapsed Timeline (This is what it looked before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed77h.png)

These are the collapsed and expanded view of the timeline.

What to do to make the timeline view collapsed by default when I open VS Code?

I right clicked several times on the Timeline view and checked all the options but nothing works!

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing is probably this bug: [Timeline view in sidebar opens automatically on launch
#197334](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197334).

[It's probably going to be fixed soon](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197334#issuecomment-1817223111) (hopefully in the November 2023 release) courtesy of John Murray in their Pull Request: [Keep Timeline view collapsed across reloads (fix #197334) #198571](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/198571). If you're interested in the nitty gritty of why the bug is/was happening, see [John's analysis here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197334#issuecomment-1816896665). The fix ended up being done by a different PR: [fix #197334 #198961](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/198961).