# Display Outline element by default

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to see the Outline of a file by default when I open the VSCode. Now every time I open the VSCode I need to go to View -> Open View... and then type Outline. Is it possible to have Outline displayed by default when I open the program?

Comment: have you tried the `...` menu in the Explorer Bar

Comment: cannot reproduce. VS Code should remember for each workspace the state of the outline view being displayed. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77522118/11107541